# Military space opera story discovering dead civilization

Tags: story-identification, space-opera

I am trying to find a story I read a few years back.
It was a space opera-type story with big military spaceships, discovering remains of a past civilization in the form of big asteroid-like supercomputers telling about their death.

At some point in the story "bubbles" form on the ship, allowing soldiers to travel through the fourth dimension.

I hope I am not mixing up things and would be really happy if someone recognized this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately when was "a few years ago?"  Was it a short story or a novel?  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any more details you can [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds a bit like brief parts of the 2010 [*Death's End*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death%27s_End) by [Cixin Liu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liu_Cixin) (first published in English in 2016), the third book of the [*Remembrance of Earth's Past*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remembrance_of_Earth%27s_Past) trilogy.

In a forshadowing scene in the book, members of a small interstellar excursion—really exiles fleeing the Earth/Trisolaran military conflict that forms the main dramatic tension of the story—stumble into a 'region' of space providing access to 4 spatial dimensions. While carefully exploring this zone, the humans encounter multidimensional artifact of some degree of artificial intelligence. Just as you describe, this AI is a monument to the former 4D civilizations that built it.

Below is the US English language cover.

[image: Death's End cover]